# How to raise a message box in case of not handled Error in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a huge in size Python script which takes much time for its
execution, runs in background and is started in a way that I can't see
its printing output.

In order to to be able to get notified when the script is finished
I raise an appropriate message box, but if the script exits because
of an Error I won't get notified.

Below a minimal code demonstrating what I am speaking about:

```
import math
try: 
    i = int('Oxff') 
except ValueError:
      ...             # some code handling the exception  
... ; pass ; ...      # some further code  
import no_such_module # in code not handled unexpected error 
... ; pass ; ...      # some further code  
# Message box notifying about successfull script run: 
from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
root.geometry('10x10+'+str(root.winfo_screenwidth()-10)+'+'+str(root.winfo_screenheight()-10))
from tkinter.messagebox import Message 
Message(title="Success", message="No Error", master=root).show()
```

So when my Python script fails due to an unexpected and therefore not
in code handled error I will not get notified at all.

I don't want to enclose the entire script code with `try: ... except: ...`
in order to handle unexpected and in code not handled errors.

**Is there in Python a way to write a function which will be run displaying a message box in case an unexpected error terminates the script?**

Comment: Does your OS provide any sort of notification system you can leverage instead of dealing with GUI elements yourself?

Comment: I am on Linux Mint (flavor of Ubuntu) and because of this question bumped into the Python signals module while trying to get a notification message box also in case the process will be for some reason killed. I am not at that level to know if there is a way of handling signals or whatever is necessary on the level of OS, so I can't give an answer to what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap in your own [`sys.excepthook`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) to handle uncaught exceptions:

```
import sys
import traceback
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror


def oops(type, value, tb):
    showerror('Error', '\n'.join(traceback.format_exception(type, value, tb)))
    sys.exit(1)


sys.excepthook = oops


print(1 / 0)
```

pops up

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can in Python write a notification function which will be run when
Python exits because of in code not handled Error using the builtin
`atexit` module. With the help of this module you can register functions
which will be executed at Python script exit.

Below code for a function which if executed at start of a Python script
will cause raising a message box when Python script exits:

```
def get_notified_about_error(): 
    import atexit
    global atexit_handler
    def atexit_handler():
        print("Script EXIT because of an ERROR")
        from tkinter import Tk
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry('10x10+'+str(root.winfo_screenwidth()-10)+'+'+str(root.winfo_screenheight()-10))
        from tkinter.messagebox import Message 
        Message(title="atexit_handler()", message="Error occured", master=root).show()
    atexit.register(atexit_handler)
get_notified_about_error()
```

In order to avoid running the registered `atexit_handler()` function
when the Python script exits without an error unregister the function
in the last line of the Python script with:

```
import atexit
atexit.unregister(atexit_handler)
```

Below the entire code which demonstrates the solution:

```
# REQUIRED HEADER:
def get_notified_about_error(): 
    import atexit
    global atexit_handler
    def atexit_handler():
        print("Script EXIT because of an ERROR")
        from tkinter import Tk
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry('10x10+'+str(root.winfo_screenwidth()-10)+'+'+str(root.winfo_screenheight()-10))
        from tkinter.messagebox import Message 
        Message(title="atexit_handler()", message="Error occured", master=root).show()
    atexit.register(atexit_handler)
get_notified_about_error()

# SCRIPT CODE: 
import math
try: 
    i = int('Oxff') 
except ValueError:
      ...             # some code handling the exception  
... ; pass ; ...      # some further code  
import no_such_module # in code not handled unexpected error 
... ; pass ; ...      # some further code  
# Message box notifying about successfull script run: 
from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
root.geometry('10x10+'+str(root.winfo_screenwidth()-10)+'+'+str(root.winfo_screenheight()-10))
from tkinter.messagebox import Message 
Message(title="Success", message="No Error", master=root).show()

# REQUIRED TRAILER:
import atexit
atexit.unregister(atexit_handler)
```

Comment: Using `atexit` for error handling is not a great approach. You can't tell what the error is, for one.

Comment: I haven't seen yet scripts enclosing the entire code in `try: ... except:...` which would handle this. What would be a better approach to achieve the  required behavior?

Comment: See my answer. :-)