Redirect stdout/stderr in tkinter GUI app when launched with **pythonw**
I want to launch a python GUI application on Windows.
To not block the console if started I need to use pythonw to run this application.
Additionally, I need to provide a batch script that does some setup and users need to run the application trough that script.
When users launch, i.e., double click, the batch script, I don't want the cmd.exe window do show.
The batch script is therefore something like this
REM set BLA=123
REM and other environment stuff and then run the GUI
pythonw myapp.py

As stdout/stderr are not available, then no error is shown when clicking the button and nobody knows what happened:
import tkinter as tk
def command():
    1 / 0
root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text="button", command=command)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()

My question is therefore, how can I redirect stdout and stderr to a GUI window (frame, messagebox or similar).

Do you want to redirect stdout and stderr, or do you want uncaught exceptions to show up as error boxes? An answer for the latter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73570696/51685

I need to do both. Thanks for the link anyway - interesting read!

Try overwriting the sys.stdout.write/sys.stderr.write methods. As far as I know, that should still work.

Then see contextlib.redirect_stdout and redirect_stderr.

as I remember there were question for this on Stackoverflow. You can assign own function to sys.stdout.write/sys.stderr.write which gets text and sends to tkinter.Label or tkinter.Text. You may also find examples which uses class with functions write(), (eventually flush()) and assign to sys.stdout and sys.stderr

python - How to make tkinter text box a stdin input receiver? - Stack Overflow in question you can see class StdoutRedirector() which is assigned to sys.stdout and sys.stderr

I could design a solution based on these answers. I will simpify it and create an answer. Thanks for the hints!
